# mod_wsgi Failed to parse WSGI script file | Exception occurred processing WSGI script | Unable to import 'site' module

Tags: python, django, apache, centos, mod-wsgi

I am using httpd with mod_wsgi with httpd on a centos 6.9 machine here are relevant files, I am trying to deploy django on an apache 2.15 version, triend to google a lot but couldnot solve the issue, any help would be appreciated

**django.conf**

```
WSGIPythonHome /home/pbadmin/venv/bin/python
WSGIPythonPath /home/pbadmin/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages


<VirtualHost *:8888>

   ServerAdmin root@localhost
   ServerName  10.0.48.40
   DocumentRoot /var/www/PBpy
   WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/PBpy/PBpy/wsgi.py

   WSGIDaemonProcess PBpy python-path=/home/pbadmin/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages


   ErrorLog "/home/pbadmin/pylogs"
   <Directory "/var/www/PBpy">
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**wsgi.py**

```
import os
import sys

#sys.path.append('/var/www/PBpy')

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "PBpy.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**error log**

```
[Thu Jun 01 12:27:24 2017] [error] [client 10.0.32.94] mod_wsgi (pid=6148): Target WSGI script '/home/pbadmin/PBpy/apache/django.wsgi' cannot b$
[Thu Jun 01 12:27:24 2017] [error] [client 10.0.32.94] mod_wsgi (pid=6148): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/pbadmin/PBpy/apach$
[Thu Jun 01 12:27:24 2017] [error] [client 10.0.32.94] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jun 01 12:27:24 2017] [error] [client 10.0.32.94]   File "/home/pbadmin/PBpy/apache/django.wsgi", line 10, in <module>
[Thu Jun 01 12:27:24 2017] [error] [client 10.0.32.94]     import django.core.handlers.wsgi
[Thu Jun 01 12:27:24 2017] [error] [client 10.0.32.94]   File "/home/pbadmin/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 3, in <
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't supposed to be setting `WSGIPythonHome` to the binary for `python` for a start. Read:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

for how to set up Python virtual environment properly.

You are also missing a `WSGIProcessGroup` directive. You aren't actually delegating the application to the daemon process group to have defined.